# How to adjust images

Tags: css

I am trying to adjust images like Reebok site , here is the screenshot
http://postimg.org/image/6lvroax27/

My **wordpress** website screenshot -->
http://postimg.org/image/ipmq9o44j/

i want to intersect two images and remove margin above image
**My website** - > **www.cardmart.tk**
Image is on homepage

---

Is it p tag  above image margin?not sure as  I Unchecked it in tiny mce but still there is margin.
Sorry for so many links

Thank You !

Comment: your image looks fine. if you were being picky set margins and padding to 0px !important;

Comment: Hi , Can you tell me thel css , I want to join  the ends of images

Comment: for what its worth i think its a fine site!

Comment: Thank You Ma'am , its so difficult when you know nothing about coding. But I made this because of people like you always there For help !

Comment: and you are welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the borders are more to do with the images themselves but i did inspect the source and there is a border of 15px around it (margin)

Set this in your css:

```
.row, .col-md-6{margin:0!important; padding:0!important}
```

this is the offending piece of code

```
<div class="col-md-6"></div></p><h6 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #424242;">Wedding Invitations</span></h6><p><span style="display:block;clear:both;height: 0px;padding-top: 20px;"></span></p><p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #928b8b; font-size: 24pt;">Are You RSVP ready?</span></p><p style="text-align: center;"><span style="display:block;clear:both;height: 0px;padding-top: 20px;"></span></p><p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #808080;"> </span><strong><span style="color: #424242; font-size: 14pt;">Take a look at our exclusive collection you will fall in love<br /> with it after all wedding is all about love &amp; commitment </span></strong></p><p></div></div></p></div></div></div><div class="so-panel widget widget_black-studio-tinymce panel-last-child" id="panel-2-1-0-1"><div class="textwidget"><p><div class="row"> <div class="col-md-6"></p>
<h6 style="text-align: center;">Print My Design</h6>
<p><span style="display:block;clear:both;height: 0px;padding-top: 20px;"></span></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 24pt; color: #808080;">Your Design + Our Print</span></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="display:block;clear:both;height: 0px;padding-top: 20px;"></span></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>You submit your design &amp; we provide our </strong><strong>quality </strong></span></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong> printing service.</strong></span></div><div class="col-md-6"> <a href="http://cardmart.tk/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/rsz_maxresdefault_1.jpg" data-rel="lightbox"><img class="alignright size-full wp-image-477" src="http://cardmart.tk/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/rsz_maxresdefault_1.jpg" alt="rsz_maxresdefault_1" width="675" height="320" /></a></p>
<p></div></div>
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you very much ! Now images are aligned properly but what about height? how can we join them?

Comment: i dont know much css , please can you tell me the css code? Thank you !

Comment: Sorry @rachel its so embarrassing for me  , i am wordpress user , i dont know css , So i havent make any changes with css . Just taking help from you & pasting it in custom css.
So please tell me the css code 
Thank you

Comment: in the inline html you have </h6><p><span style="display:block;clear:both;height: 0px;padding-top: 20px;">  just before Print my design. Remove it. That might do the trick. Its also present just before wedding invitations. If you're not happy remove it there too (the padding only )

Comment: Lol i want to give you 100 upvotes , you are helping me so much , but we can only edit php in wordpress (which i dont know ) Can you tell me the css code? for removing 20px padding
Thanks & yea upvote sure :)

Comment: oh if its php then the padding is auto generated i think. you might have to leave it as is.  You could try h6{padding: 0px!important;} that might work

Comment: Lol , i am new to stackflow,   trying to find the upvote button :P 
where it is?

Comment: Thanks For giving Your time :)  You Are awesome . But that code didnt work .

Comment: its a span thing then it's in a span try putting span after the h6 like h6 span{padding:0!important;}

Comment: No problem .
Thank You once again .

Comment: ooh! i have a spark of inspiration! try h6 p{padding-top:0px!important;}

Comment: Coders can never run away from the problem Lol . 
But still not working. :D :D 
Thanks You are trying so much :P

Comment: damn - i really thought i had it there